# Basic fun Encryption using sed in Unix

Tags: unix, encryption, sed

I want to make a command using sed to encrypt a txt file to an encryption of my liking, I know how to substitute single characters like this:

```
sed s/a/*/
```

but I want to run through a-Z and 0-9. I imagine I would have to do this char by char but don't know the most efficient way of going about it...

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Such an "encryption" would be extremely easy to break. So what is the point?

Comment: I'm not going to encrypt/keep anything important it's just more useful for me learning Unix and the sed command in general.

Comment: You want to use the ['y' command of sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49).

Comment: Learning is usually performed by practicing (and failing) a lot. This sounds you want a pre-made made meal to learn how to cook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap some characters of the input:

```
 sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\2\3\1/g' input_file > encrypted
```

and decrypt:

```
 sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\3\1\2/g' encrypted
```

Comment: Plz add a bit of information on how it's working. I know parenthesis is used for grouping (and replacing the group) and '\' is used to escape a character. But I'm unable to understand how dot is used. At least some hints would be appreciated.  Anyway I'm using this for simple obfuscation. ;-)

Comment: Okay. I got it. A moment after I posted the comments, I understood what's going on. The slash is used to escape the opening and closing parenthesis. Still I request to add some hints how its working , for those how will read this ans in future.